# Doing python manage.py syncdb resets my admin changes in Pinax

Tags: python, django, pinax

I run Pinax 0.9.2a **basic** starter project. When I go to admin panel to change the site's name, it saves correctly and displays accordingly on the web page. But after I run `python manage.py syncdb` I get the following output, as well as my page title being reset back to *example.com*.

```
Creating tables ...
Creating table outfits_outfit
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 1 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

I must add that my *Recent Actions* history are still there, in the admin panel.

**EDIT: The problem was that Pinax sample project already comes with an init_data JSON file in the Fixture folder. And surely enough it was overriding my site's name with example.com.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Edit the site instance** in the admin
2. **Export it**: `manage.py dumpdata sites`
3. **Add the JSON code** for the site in `fixtures/initial_data.json`

Everytime you run syncdb, `fixtures/initial_data.json` is loaded.